# Fiddler shows DNS Lookup failure

Tags: networking, dns, fiddler

On my desktop I run Visual studio web server cassini and fiddler as a proxy, then I connect to a web site running in Cassini using an iPad connected via wireless.

This has always worked since I installed and unistalled the MVC pack for visual studio.

Now I get this message from fiddler (it is sent to the iPad):

```
[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "http://175.33.22.116" failed. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

There are similar posts with this message, but none of them with my setup.

Can you suggest what to check?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the traffic from your IPAD  client is malformed. Are you using anything in Fiddler (e.g. Tools > HOSTS) to change the traffic? If not, the bug is on the client; e.g. something is trying to connect to `http://http://175.33.22.116` which isn't legal (due to the double http:// within the string).